# Looping over a string list

Tags: list, foreach, cmake

I would like to loop over list of items, given in a string. As required by CMake, the items are separated by semicolons. The following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FOREACH(LETTER "a;b;c")
  MESSAGE("<<${LETTER}>>")
ENDFOREACH()
```

interpretes the string `"a;b;c"` as string literal. In contrast, when assigning `"a;b;c"` to a variable first, all works out as expected.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(MYLIST "a;b;c")
FOREACH(LETTER ${MYLIST})
  MESSAGE("<<${LETTER}>>")
ENDFOREACH()
```

Is this the recommended way for looping over a list or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The source of your confusion is probably CMake's peculiar interpretation of quoted strings.

For example, the following all iterate over the list of strings correctly:

```
(1) foreach(LETTER a b c) [...]
(2) foreach(LETTER a;b;c) [...]
(3) set(MYLIST "a;b;c")
    foreach(LETTER ${MYLIST}) [...]
```

The only case where this does not work is

```
(4) foreach(LETTER "a;b;c") [...]
```

The reason why `(1)` and `(2)` work is found in [CMake's language manual for unquoted arguments](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument):

> Unquoted argument content consists of all text in a contiguous block
>   of allowed or escaped characters. Both Escape Sequences and Variable
>   References are evaluated. The resulting value is **divided in the same
>   way Lists divide into elements**. Each non-empty element is given to the
>   command invocation as an argument. Therefore an unquoted argument may
>   be given to a command invocation as zero or more arguments.

Note that this is different from [quoted arguments](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument), which also evaluate Escape Sequences and Variable References, but do not do the list expansion. This explains why `(4)` fails.

The interesting question now is why `(3)` still succeeds. [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) will accept both single value and list value arguments. In fact, everything before the closing `)` or one of the keywords `CACHE` or `PARENT_SCOPE` is considered part of the value. As such, the following two commands are equivalent:

```
set(MYLIST "a;b;c")
set(MYLIST a;b;c)
```

In both cases the value of `MYLIST` will be `a;b;c` (without the quotes).

When we now expand `${MYLIST}` into another command, you can think of it performing a simple string replacement with the value of `MYLIST`, which is `a;b;c`. The resulting command will then get expanded via the rules of of quoted or unquoted arguments. That is, the following will work:

```
foreach(LETTER ${MYLIST}) [...]
```

while this will not:

```
foreach(LETTER "${MYLIST}") [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, consider if you type all values in `foreach` call, like `foreach (N 1 2 3)`, or if you want to rather expand a variable like `foreach (N ${MY_NUMBER_LIST})`.

While the accepted-answer expands the variable on the line, **making code-injection possible** (if variable is set outside your script), it still may work for most cases.

**But for secure looping over variables** (without expanding), try below:

```
# My dummy data.
set (_my_list "A B C")
string (REPLACE " " ";" _my_list "${_my_list}")

# Actual looping.
foreach (my_entry IN LISTS _my_list)

    # All done! do something with ${my_entry}, for example:
    if (NOT my_entry IN_LIST _my_other_list)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "_my_list has ${my_entry} but _my_other_list does not!!")
    endif()

endforeach()
```